# Approximate de-duplication

Tags: r, join, duplicates, fuzzy-comparison, record-linkage

Suppose I have a dataset like this:

[image: example data]

that I need to examine for possible duplicates. Here, the 2nd and 3rd rows are suspected duplicates. I'm aware of string distance methods as well as approximate matches for numeric variables. But **have the two approaches been combined?** Ultimately, I'm looking for an approach that I can implement in R.

Comment: Are the second and third row potential duplicates because their timestamps are in close proximity, their strings are similar, or both?

Comment: Both. Actually, in the example, I also made `freq` an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a straightforward approach to this problem. You could treat each column separatly: `datetime` as timestamp proximity, `string` as string proximity (Levenshtein distance) and `freq` as numeric distance. You can then individually rank each row for each column in increasing fashion. Row numbers that rank high in all three of the metrics (**least** differences) are the better candidates to be duplicates. You can then choose the threshold for which you consider a dulicated case.

Comment: Thanks. This was going to be my default approach. I was hoping something similar to the package `fuzzyjoin` existed allowing for a mixture of string distances and numeric distances depending on the variable.

Comment: When you say timestamp proximity, do you have something specific in mind? I was planning to treat it `as.numeric(datetime)`

Comment: You can use `POSIXlt` notation and use the `difftime` function like `difftime(time1,time2, units="sec")` and it will return time difference in seconds. **edit** I see `as.numeric()` turns time into seconds, thus returning the same result. Still, with `POSIXit` you can select output as minutes, hours ...